# Image on canvas vanishes on click event

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabric.js to implement a application that will allow users to select a image template and then write some text over the image and then export the image. I tried an preliminary implementation. The problem I had is that after making the image appear in the canvas the image disappears after I click the image.

This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("entering the ad_man js file");

    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    };
    img.src = 'http://ovtoaster.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/cc-logo.jpg';
    var textCharsInfo = function (textObj) {
        var results = { charDims: [], totalLength : 0 };
        if (textObj && textObj.text && textObj.text.length > 0) {
            var str = '';
            var prevWidth = 0;
            for (var i = 0, length = textObj.text.length; i < length; i++) {
                var c = textObj.text.charAt(i);
                str += c;
                var txtObjForCalc = new fabric.IText(str, { 
                    fontFamily: textObj.fontFamily,
                    fontWeight: textObj.fontWeight,
                    fontSize: textObj.fontSize,
                    left: 2000,
                    top: 2000,
                    useNative: true 
                });

                canvas.add(txtObjForCalc).renderAll();
                var charWidth = txtObjForCalc.width - prevWidth;
                prevWidth = txtObjForCalc.width;
                results.charDims.push({ width: charWidth, height: txtObjForCalc.height });
                canvas.remove(txtObjForCalc);
                txtObjForCalc = null;
            }
            results.totalLength = prevWidth;
        }

        return results;
    };


    var text = new fabric.IText("This is text that is curved along an arc.", { 
        fontFamily: 'Italianno',
        fontWeight: '',
        fontSize: 40,
        left: 250,
        top: 250,
        useNative: true 
    });
    canvas.add(text);
    canvas.renderAll();;
});
```

This the html part:

```
<h1>Hello World test</h1>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400">test</canvas> 
<img src="http://ovtoaster.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/cc-logo.jpg" id="image_man"></img>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aravindgd/74jFy/). How do I retain the image?

---

Here is an updated version of the fiddle with more changes. I was able make the initial picture work the way I want. Now on changing the background image on click make the new image vanish as well. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aravindgd/84L42/4/).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are adding the image into canvas in native style, when you used this style the image object is not added to fabric canvas, When you clicked on drawn text, the fabric redraws all shapes which are added to canvas, so unadded image would be disappear.

Add **image** this way into canvas

```
var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img);
canvas.add(imgInstance);
```

Instead of native style

```
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/74jFy/1/)

Comment: Please recheck the js fiddle you gave me. Both the image as well the text vanishes.

Comment: @Arvind, If I click on "This is text chat is curved....", then both images and text are displaying, Can you please tell me in which way these are disappearing like click some where..or anyway. Well in demo I removed the function `textCharsInfo()` but this does not effect the result.

Comment: Yeah this works in Chrome browser only, I tried lot but did not make run on firefox, however can you please put the image's src is static like `../cc-logo.jpg` not `http://ovtoaster.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/cc-logo.jpg`

Comment: the jsfiddle you gave me is still not working. Please take a look at the update question

Comment: Why? Changing the url? what difference does that make? I removed the textCharsInfo() function as well that was not required. Thanks.